# Why using a IR sensor instead of a IR sensor module (1838B)?

Tags: arduino, infrared

I bought an Arduino kit and it contains two sensors for IR (if I'm correct).

The first is a looking exactly like a LED but black (but heard it is a IR receiver).

The other item looks like [this](http://www.produktinfo.conrad.com/datenblaetter/175000-199999/184288-da-01-en-IR_RECEIVER_2_7_5_5V_OS_1838B.pdf); which is an 1838B.

Why would I use the first LED-looking like part instead of the 1838B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *black LED* is photo transistor. This means the current through this part is controlled by the IR light intensity on a certain wavelength. The output is a real analog signal without any processing and signal forming.

The three pin *1838B* is an IC, which is also a IR receiver with integrated pre processing of the analog signal. In this particular case this devices has a \$38\,kHz\$ filter, which corresponds to the IR carrier frequency of some IR remotes. It also demodulates the IR signal and generates a digital output. Perfect for reading data from remotes.

According to your use case, you can pick either of them.

Comment: Thank you ... well I have a dedicated IR remote so I guess the 1838B is better, but to know more about the background, maybe I should start with the photo transistor.